# What is the name of this D&D campaign I played?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

A long time ago I was playing with a friend but I don't remember where I could read more information about it or what its called.

Its based on D&D but its kind of a global thing where the world evolves as IRL time passes. Event-based pretty much. Where people who have played it a long time have been written into the lore.

It's a pen and paper game I am asking about. It's based on Dungeons and Dragons lore and set in the same setting, but I don't think it was Dungeons and Dragons.

I was playing a wraith who was possessing the body of a priest. And was playing a necromancer. Had big issues with those pesky witch hunters.

I do know this was not something my friend made by himself, it was run with the help of the D&D books and information from online. The world is kind of a community thing, with lore that evolves as people play it. So some players who have played it a long time, will have their characters either as living or dead entities in the lore.

I believe we last played it about 2–3 years ago.

Anyway.... would like to read myself into that again, but I don't remember what its called or what to search to find more info. Please help me determine what we were playing.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. It's not really clear what you're trying to ask here. Are you talking about an RPG system, or a D&D campaign, or a non-tabletop game, or what?

Comment: Updated, not fully sure what to ask too be honest. Was a while ago so its a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Can you give us at least an estimate of how long ago this was? Also do you recall this adventure being run from a book or do you think your friend had created this as something of their own? Any more details you can provide would be helpful, as it is I'm not sure it is enough to go on.

Comment: updated again. Not sure if i should add it as comments or if you get a notification when the post is updated.

Comment: (You can address a particular user by prefacing the user's name with the `@` symbol. Similarly, a question jumps to the top of the Active Questions list when it's edited. You needn't signal edits either: the site tracks those automatically.) With just *one proper name* of one of the "living or dead entities in the lore," the Wisdom of Crowds, I'm certain, could handle this. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to edit this to be more concise and help people pick out the actual information. Feel free to roll back the edit or re-edit it if you feel like I removed or altered important parts.

Comment: I don't think you *can* use the D&D setting in another type of game, so I think this is just a specific D&D campaign. Do you have any information about how events were recorded or what kind of events happened?

Comment: @Ifusaso It’s far from impossible — I’m running a Forgotten Realms campaign in GURPS right now. “D&D lore” can be used in literally infinite different RPGs.

Comment: I think what is meant is that you aren't allowed to use any d&d setting in a commercial product because it's copyrighted

Comment: Try to answer these questions: 1) What years did you play it exactly? 2) Which edition, or what was on the Player's Handbook cover (i.e. Brown with gems = 3e, blue with two characters = 4e, red with giant = 5e)? 3) Was it Greyhawk (gods like Pelor, Nerull), Forgotten Realms (gods like Lathander, Kelemvor, Mystra) or Eberron (Sovereign Host, Blood of Vol), or none of these? 4) Did you have to do paperwork other than your own character sheet? 5) Would the names "Living Greyhawk" or "Living Forgotten Realms" ring a bell? 6) Was it in a European style setting, or a desert, or something else?

Comment: I sounds like a persistent homebrew setting to me. My friend is part of a very long-standing one online. Did you happen to play online?